# What is the difference between the measure and onMeasure methods of an Android View?

Tags: android

I see that both measure and onMeasure are often included in the view lifecycle images, but I am having a hard time differentiating between them and how they are called upon. The same confusion stands for layout and onLayout/ draw and onDraw.

Answer (score 2):

Measure is an action to do something but onMeasure is the listener for the action which means you can track Measure Action in  onMeasure.

to learn what Measure and on onMeasure do read this article.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws